# How to get a parameter from url in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have a url like this:

**http://localhost:3000/1**

The "1" is the user id as parameter, how can I get it in react js?

Comment: are you using react-router ?

Comment: are you using react router or react router dom as a package for routing in react app ?

Comment: I have added a working example, is this what you are looking for, in the codesandox url you can type product/2, so it will display whatever id you have typed in the codesandbox url https://codesandbox.io/s/59564616-so-react-routing-getting-params-e1flt

Comment: ```this.props.match.params.parm_name```

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS the codesandox was helpful, thnks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If router is like this

```
<Route exact path="/category/:id" component={ProductList}/>
```

Access like this

```
this.props.match.params.id
```

for your reference [URL Parameters with React Router](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-url-parameters/)

Comment: It works, thks! I didn't know the Router so I had a little work

Answer (score 6):

FWIW it's much easier now using hooks in React Router DOM v5 ([link](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams))

In Router define routes as normal:

```
<Route path="/users/:id" ...
```

And in the Component, simply deconstruct the useParams hook:

```
const { id } = useParams();
```

It's that simple!

Answer (score 1):

**==============================Using component==================**

```
<Route path="/users/:id" component={UserPage}/> 

this.props.match.params.id
```

**===============================Using render====================**

```
<Route path="/users/:id" render={(props) => <UserPage {...props} />}/> 

this.props.match.params.id
```

For Query Parameter:
https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string